# 'function' object has no attribute 'all' on DetailView

Tags: python, django

Can someone please give me a quick explanation as to what I'm doing wrong I got, `'function' object has no attribute 'all'`, this error. and i've used DetailView.

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from main import models

class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model_name = models.BlogTitle
    template_name = 'main/blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'object'

    def queryset(self):
        return models.BlogTitle.objects.order_by('title')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class BlogTitle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 64, default = False)        
    title = models.OneToOneField(BlogTitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
```

urls.py

```
path('blogs/<int:pk>', auth(views.BlogDetail.as_view()), name = 'blog'),
```

blog.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    

    {{ object.title }}
    {{ object.category }}
    {{ object.content }}

{% endblock %}
```

I tried `objects.all()` this also, but I didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Most generic view mixins that ship with django provide an overridable *class attribute* [`queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.queryset) and and overridable *method* [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset). So either do:

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    # ...
    queryset = models.BlogTitle.objects.order_by('title')
```

or

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = models.BlogTitle   # not "model_name"
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.order_by('title')
```

By mixing up the naming, your view now accesses `self.queryset.all()`, but since `self.queryset` is now a function, you are seeing the error. Generally, you would use `queryset` in cases where the queryset does not depend on the particular request, and `get_queryset` when it does (as you have access to `self.request`) or to a lesser degree if, for some reason, defining the queryset already requires a database query to be executed which should never happen at module level. The puzzling part to me is that you override it just to change the ordering which makes little sense for a detail view which will only use the queryset to extract a single instance.